# mathematical analysis

Tags: integration, analysis, limits

Can anyone help me find this limit :

Let the function $f(x)$ has continous derivative in the interval $[0,1] $and for every $ n\in{\Bbb{N}} $:

$$x(n)=f(\frac1n)+f(\frac2n)+...+f(\frac{n−1}n)$$

Using the definite integral find the following limit :

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x(n+1)−x(n)=?$$

We can solve this using the mean value theorem, but I have no idea how to start solving this.

Please help me.

Comment: @Jack's wasted life: Why did you delete the answer??? You just would have to turn around $x(n)-x(n+1)$...

Comment: @zoli my previous answer was wrong : }

Comment: @Jack'swastedlife : What went wrong? I was about to give the s(h?)ame answer. Then I saw yours (with a little mistake). Just FMI what did we do wrong?

Comment: @zoli The integrand is $xf'(x)$ instead of just $f'(x)$ :)

Comment: @Jack'swastedlife: Now I don't understand: Why $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{kf'(\xi_{k,n})\over {n+1}}{1\over n}  \not \approx \int_0^1f'(x)\ dx?$ (Is $\frac{k}{n(n+1)} \not =\Delta_{k,n}?$) Why $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{kf'(\xi_{k,n})\over {n+1}}{1\over n}  \approx \int_0^1xf(x)\ dx?$

Comment: @Jack'swastedlife: The last question is "Why ... $\approx \int_0^1xf'(x)dx$?"

Comment: @zoli look at $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{k\over n(n+1)}=0.5$. After taking the limit the sum does not add up to $1$=length of the interval we're integrating over. So it doesn't correspond to a meaningful partition of $[0,1]$ whereas $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{1\over n}=1$.

Comment: @Jack'swastedlife: Yes, I can see:
$$0<\frac 1{n+1}<\frac{1}{n}<\frac{2}{n+1}<\frac{2}{n}\cdots<\frac{i}{n+1}<\frac{i}{n}<\cdots< \frac{n-1}{n+1}< \frac{n-1}{n}<\frac{n}{n+1}<1?$$ 
There is something between $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{2}{n+1}$ which I did not take into account...
But this is wromg:$\qquad{k\over n}<\xi_{k,n}<{k\over n+1}$ because $\frac{k}{n+1}<\frac{k}{n}.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By MVT
$$f\left({k\over n}\right)-f\left({k\over n+1}\right)={kf'(\xi_{k,n})\over n(n+1)},\qquad{k\over n+1}<\xi_{k,n}<{k\over n}\\
\Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left[f\left({k\over n}\right)-f\left({k\over n+1}\right)\right]-f\left({n\over n+1}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} {kf'(\xi_{k,n})\over n(n+1)}-f\left({n\over n+1}\right)\\
\Rightarrow x(n)-x(n+1)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} {kf'(\xi_{k,n})\over n(n+1)}-f\left({n\over n+1}\right)\\ 
\Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty} (x(n)-x(n+1))=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{kf'(\xi_{k,n})\over {n+1}}{1\over n}-f(1)\\
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\xi_{k,n}f'(\xi_{k,n}){1\over n}-f(1)\\
=\int_0^1xf'(x)dx-f(1)=-\int_{0}^1f(x)dx$$

So the required limit is $$\int_{0}^1f(x)dx$$

Comment: you're welcome :)